# Creating transition matrix per indexed Time interval

Tags: r, matrix, transition, probability

I have a dataset on the transition of users between states (9 in total) in a specific time interval. This dataset will be used for a markov chain model. In total there are 96 time intervals, thus: for every user there are 96 observations each of which provides the specified time interval, a start location and an end location. A state that combines two locations simply means that the user is still in transition between the two states.

Below is a fictional dataset. In this example, unlike the actual dataset, start and end location are not necessarily linked, but I believe this will serve just as well as an illustration of the problem.

```
ID <- rep(1:10, each = 96)
TimeInterval <- rep(1:96, 10)
Locations <- c("Home", "Bakery", "Grocery", "Home-Bakery", "Home-Grocery", "Bakery-Home", "Bakery-Grocery", "Grocery-Home", "Grocery-Bakery")
startLocation <- sample(Locations, 960, replace = TRUE)
endLocation <- sample(Locations, 960, replace = TRUE)
df <- data.frame(ID, TimeInterval, startLocation, endLocation)
```

I want to calculate a transition matrix for every time interval, where the transition probability is calculated by the probability of transitioning into a state/location given the state/location at the previous time interval. For instance, to calculate the transition probability matrix for TimeInterval 37 the probability of being in a certain state  in TimeInterval 37 given the state in TimeInterval 36 is taken.

This will result in a total of 96 transition matrices. The probability of transitioning from one state (Location) to another given a specific timeframe then depends on probability of all users combined.

However, I do not know how to aggregate the results of the individual transitions. What would be an efficient way to calculate these matrices?

The transition matrix per time interval should be a 9x9 matrix that includes all the states.

Edit:

A (very ugly) dplyr solution that worked for a single transition matrix:

```
Interval36 <- df %>% filter(TimeInterval== 36)
Interval37 <- df %> filter(TimeInterval == 37)

timeBlock37 <- as.data.frame(cbind(Interval37$journey, Interval36$journey))
mTimeBlock37 <- as.data.frame.matrix(table(timeBlock37))
timeBlock <- prop.table(mTimeBlock37 )
timeBlock
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself, although not in the most elegant way with quite a unstructured for-loop.

```
matrixList <- list()
states <- Locations
for(i in 1:96){
  i <- ifelse(i < 96,i + 1, 96)
  t1 <- df %>% filter(timeBlock == i)
  j <- ifelse(i < 96,i + 1, 96)
  t2 <- df%>% filter(timeBlock == j)


  timeBlock <- as.data.frame(cbind(t1[,8], t2[,8]))
  mTime <- as.data.frame.matrix(table(timeBlock))
  timeBlock <- prop.table(mTime)
  timeBlock <- as.matrix(timeBlock)

  mat1 <- matrix(0, nrow = 9, ncol = 9)
  colnames(mat1) <- states
  rownames(mat1) <- states

  colsNeeded <- colnames(mat1)[colnames(mat1) %in% colnames(timeBlock)]
  rowsNeeded <- rownames(mat1)[rownames(mat1) %in% rownames(timeBlock)]
  mat1[rowsNeeded, colsNeeded] <- timeBlock[rowsNeeded, colsNeeded] 
  matrixList[[i]] <- mat1

}
```

I created an empty matrix in the for-loop that could be populated with the transition matrix to take into account for the situations where not all states would appear within a certain timeframe.

If someone still has a more elegant/cleaner solution, feel free to contribute for future readers.